# How do I get a shell script to continue copying files after one copy command stalls?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, cygwin

I'm running Cygwin on WinXP.  I have written the following shell script to copy files from a network drive to a remote server ...

```
scp -P 9998 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L1*TE* dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level1
scp -P 9998 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L1*SE* dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/student/ela/level1
scp -P 9998 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L2*TE* dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level2
scp -P 9998 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L2*SE* dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/student/ela/level2
```

The problem is when I run this script, occassionally I'll get errors like the below ("No such file or directory") and then the script will stall.

```
sh copy_files.sh    
...
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_12_SE.pdf                                                                                                           100%  771KB  51.4KB/s   00:15
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_13_SE.pdf                                                                                                           100%  716KB  55.0KB/s   00:13
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_14_SE.pdf                                                                                                           100%  966KB  50.8KB/s   00:19
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_15_SE.pdf                                                                                                            71%  640KB  36.9KB/s   00:06 ETA
//tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_15_SE.pdf: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I can get the script to continue copying files even when this error message comes up?

Comment: Do you consider to use something more suitable than scp? For example rsync does extremely good job for this kind of needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy one file at a time.  That way, the failed copy does not kill the script and the other copies.  Do this in a loop...

```
for i in //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L1*TE*
do
    scp -P 9998 "$i" dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level1
done

for i in //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L1*SE*
do
    scp -P 9998 "$i" dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level1
done

for i in //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L2*TE*
do
    scp -P 9998 "$i" dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level2
done

for i in //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L2*SE*
do
    scp -P 9998 "$i" dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level2
done
```

Comment: Well, this way will not allow the script to continue once it runs into bad conditions, it will just stale again.

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using is scp copying from network drive. Probably network problems are causing that the whole script stalls when the source file (scp is just copying) or target became unavailable.
The best way before making such an transfers is first to copy the files to local buffer, check them if necessary, archive them to one file and then send them to the target server already in desirable directory structure.
This way give you better knowledge of what or which side is failing.

So far to the scriptng best practices of such a transfer script.

Concentrating only to small fragment, the scp line - one copy comand is exactly this line:

```
scp -P 9998 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L2*TE* \
            dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level2
```

You are using 4 such commands in your script not giving the chance the other lines to continue if one hangs. So in your algorithm following way would be better:

```
scp -P 9998 <sourceL1TE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -P 9998 <sourceL2TE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -P 9998 <sourceL1SE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -P 9998 <sourceL2SE> <targetL2TE> &
```

The ampersand will send each line to the background so the others will start as well without need to wait for the previous to finish.

Next, you use scp in batchmode, without notifying scp to behave as in batchmode. You should consider:

```
scp -Bq -P 9998 <sourceL1TE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -Bq -P 9998 <sourceL2TE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -Bq -P 9998 <sourceL1SE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -Bq -P 9998 <sourceL2SE> <targetL2TE> &
```

It will enable rest of script to continue.

Now with knowledge of some transfer problems causing occasionaly scp to stale, you can do more with stale problem by adding timeout option. It can help to stop the scp if the connection gets too long.

```
scp -Bq -o ConnectTimeout 30 -P 9998 <sourceL1TE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -Bq -o ConnectTimeout 30 -P 9998 <sourceL2TE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -Bq -o ConnectTimeout 30 -P 9998 <sourceL1SE> <targetL2TE> &
scp -Bq -o ConnectTimeout 30 -P 9998 <sourceL2SE> <targetL2TE> &
```

And et cetera.

There are many ways how to employ bash scripting and scp options and other utilities to do it better. The above is only good start. You can even consider to follow what  failed and do a restart of scp for failed sources.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing the log

```
sh copy_files.sh    
...
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_12_SE.pdf                                                                                                           100%  771KB  51.4KB/s   00:15
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_13_SE.pdf                                                                                                           100%  716KB  55.0KB/s   00:13
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_14_SE.pdf                                                                                                           100%  966KB  50.8KB/s   00:19
cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_15_SE.pdf                                                                                                            71%  640KB  36.9KB/s   00:06 ETA
//tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_15_SE.pdf: No such file or directory
```

Its clear that the scp command couldn't find the file `cb_sb_ela_miu_L1_U2_activity2_15_SE.pdf` in that direcotry. `scp` is a fairly simple tool, but will throw error if the source you are trying to copy doesn't exist at all. I "may" be possible that by the time the `scp` command reaches the file (using the wild card) the file is moved or deleted. Also, it is suggested that you use `recursive` flag for wild card copies like

```
scp -Bpqr //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L1*TE* dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level1
```

You can also perform file checks for each file to see if the file is present before performing the `scp` like below. this way you are always certain that the file you are trying to transfer does exist.

```
#copies all level1 files to level1 directory
for file in `ls -1 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L1*`
do
   if [ -f $file ] then
     scp -Bpq $file dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level1
   fi
done

#copies all level2 files to level2 directory
for file in `ls -1 //tdggendska10/vig-preview-dmz-prod/docs/sbo/pdf/*ela*L2*`
do
   if [ -f $file ] then
     scp -Bpq $file dalvarado@localhost:/var/www/html/sbo/2010/teacher/ela/level2
   fi
done
```